# Output of 'ls' changes every time it runs in CIFS mounted windows share - RHEL 4

Tags: linux, cifs, rhel4

I have a RHEL 4 server in our organisation. One windows (2003) share is mounted on the server using CIFS. Output mount shows something like this:

```
//windows.server.fqdn/share on /mnt/shared1 type cifs (rw,mand)
```

/etc/fstab shows:

```
//windows.server.fqdn/share    /mnt/shared1    cifs    auto,uid=500,gid=500,username=windows_username,password=windows_password    0 0
```

Now in this shared1 folder, if I run 'ls', the output is different each time:

```
[user@server shared1]$ pwd
/mnt/shared1
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
85
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
172
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
1392
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
9109
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
7072
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
9109
[user@server shared1]$ ls | wc -l
4708
```

It should show 9109 files every time but I'm just not getting why it changes every single time. The data is quite static.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That is odd behavior, but please keep in mind that both of those operating systems are End of life and most hardware that still runs it is probably well past its prime too...

Comment: That is true but in large corporate environments things don't get upgraded all the time. We still have extended life support for RHEL4 from Red Hat and I expect it to continue until the very last day possible. So I'm looking for a way to fix this instead of waiting for the server to be upgraded.